# Optional relationship on ERD diagram

Tags: database-design, modeling, data-modeling

Upon generating an entity-relationship diagram of my database I observed several occurrence like this:

[image]

This diagram (in IDEF1X notation) shows the following:

1. Our team's DB convention is that each primary table (i.e., not an association-type table) has its own unique primary key called `db_id`.
2. `iam_projects.db_id` is a foreign key in `iam_project_rules` (the `project_id` field), hence the connecting line.
3. `iam_projects.db_id` is **not** part of the primary key of `iam_project_rules` (hence the dotted line style).
4. A given`iam_projects.db_id` may appear zero or more times in `iam_project_rules` (hence the solid circle on the right end of the connecting line).

Now, here's what my question is about.
As I understand the notation, the diamond on the left end of the connecting line changes the left side from "one" to "zero or one". In words, that posits this claim to be **true**:

> There may exist a row in `iam_project_rules` whose `project_id` does
>   **not** appear in `iam_projects`.

But if `iam_project_rules.project_id` is a foreign key to `iam_projects`, which it is, then that claim must be **false**.

Where is the error in my analysis or assumptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [IDEF1X cheat sheet](http://www.32geeks.com/classes/resources/IDEF1X_Cheat_Sheet), the diamond shows a relationship of an optional `iam_project` with zero, one or many `iam_project_rules`.

The *optional* can only be on the `iam_project` side, since `iam_project_rules` is already "optional" (since there can be zero rules associated with an `iam_project`).

This is possible since the relation is between independent entities, i.e. both could exist without the other:

> **Independent Entities**: An entity which does not depend upon any other entity in a model for its identification.
>   **Dependent Entities**: Depend both for their existence and their identification upon other entities in the model.

This means that:

> There may exist a row in `iam_project_rules` whose `project_id` is
>   null, which means that the rule is independent of any project.

If you want to have a non-optional relationship, you need to add a `NOT NULL` constraint on your foreign key.

Another alternative could be to align your data model with the IDEFX1 semantic and make `iam_project_rule` dependent on `iam_project` by including the foreign key `project_id` in its the primary key.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I thought it might be a NULL issue of some sort, but every field in both tables is already defined with a `NOT NULL` constraint. If that is the only possibility, then perhaps the diagram generator has a bug (I am using [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)). Let me know if you have other thoughts.

Comment: @MichaelSorens yes, the generator must have some bugs, because whatever the notation, a non null foreign key clearly indicates that it’s not optional. So the diagram is not consistent with the semantic that we can deduce from the db constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I posted a [bug report](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/7019) on dbeaver so we will see what they have to say.